# Problems Building a stack using dynamic memory (C)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to learn data structures, therefore I made an exercise which we read a string from the user, and then we evaluate the string, to check if the parentheses are well formatted, such as input: `(()`, output: `no`, they are not well formatted. Although when I try to run my code, not only does it gives the wrong output, put it shows me the error: `free(): invalid pointer`. I ran valgrind with my code and it shows me: `Invalid free() ... Address.. is 12 bytes before a block of size 16 alloc´d` I will post a snippet of my code below.
I am a beginner so any help would be appreciated, I am all ears for criticism too.

```
typedef struct {
    int *v;    
    int cap;    
    int sz;
} stack;

stack *build() {
    stack *new = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    new->v = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    new->cap = 4;
    new->sz = 0;
    return new;
}

int is_empty(stack *s) {
    return s->sz == 0;
}

int push(stack *s, int e) {
    int success = 1;

    if (s->sz == s->cap) {
        int *tmp = (int *)realloc(s->v, (s->cap + 1) * sizeof( int));
        if ((success = tmp != NULL)) {
            s->v = tmp;
            ++s->cap;
        }
    }

    if (success) {
        s->v[s->sz++] = e;
    }

    return success;
}

int top(stack *s) {
    return *(s->v);
}

int pop(stack *s) {
    int value;

    if (is_empty(s))
        return -1;

    value = *(s->v);
    s->v--;
    s->sz--;
    return value;   
}

void destroy(stack *s) {
    s->v -= s->sz + 1;
    free(s->v);
    free(s);
}

int match(char p1, char p2) {
    if (p1 == '(')
        return (p1 - p2) == '(' - ')';
    else if (p1 == '[')
        return (p1 - p2) == '[' - ']';
    else
        return (p1 - p2) == '{' - '}';
}

int main() {
    int c;
    stack *s = build();
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{')
             push(s, c);
        else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
            if (!match(pop(s), c)) {
                printf("no\n");
                destroy(s);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    puts((is_empty(s)) ? "yes" : "no");
    destroy(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the function free is in destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `pop()` and `destroy()`: you modify `s->v` instead of updating `s->sz`.  Pass a modified value of `s->v` to `free` causes undefined behavior, which valgrind catches.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *v;    
    int cap;    
    int sz;
} stack;

stack *build(void) {
    stack *new = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->v = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    new->cap = 4;
    new->sz = 0;
    return new;
}

int is_empty(stack *s) {
    return s->sz == 0;
}

int push(stack *s, int e) {
    if (s->sz == s->cap) {
        int *tmp = (int *)realloc(s->v, (s->cap + 1) * sizeof(int));
        if (tmp == NULL)
            return 0;
        s->v = tmp;
        s->cap += 1;
    }
    s->v[s->sz++] = e;
    return 1;
}

int top(stack *s) {
    if (is_empty(s))
        return -1;
    else
        return s->v[s->sz - 1];
}

int pop(stack *s) {
    if (is_empty(s))
        return -1;
    else
        return s->v[--s->sz];
}

void destroy(stack *s) {
    free(s->v);
    free(s);
}

int match(char p1, char p2) {
#define MATCH(a, b)  if (p1 == (a)) return p2 == (b)
    MATCH( '(' , ')' );
    MATCH( '[' , ']' );
    MATCH( '{' , '}' );
#undef MATCH
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int res = 0;
    int c;
    stack *s = build();
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{')
            push(s, c);
        else
        if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
            if (!match(pop(s), c)) {
                res = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (res == 0 && !is_empty(s))
        res = 2;
    puts(res == 0 ? "yes" : "no");
    destroy(s);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Implemented it and it run smootlhy! My error was to move the pointer of the element to "point" to last element, now I have a better understanding of stacks, thank you!

Comment: I also loved how remade the "match" function definitely going to steal it for my next uni project :)

Comment: @stfp04: be careful with macros, they tend to make the code more difficult to read and check, and it is easy to get them wrong.  I only use one because you seem to like symmetry... A lot of practice is needed, so enjoy the ride :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors.

The first one is that the function `top` should return the last added item. Also if the stack is empty your function implementation will invoke undefined behavior.

The function can look the following way

```
int top( stack *s, int *value ) 
{
    int success = !is_empty( s );
  
    if ( success ) *value = s->v[s->sz-1];

    return success;
}
```

and called like for example

```
int value;

if ( top( s, &value ) )
{
    printf( "Top value is %d\n", value );
}
```

The function `pop` should return nothing. It is the function `top` that provides an access to the top element of the stack. The function can look like

```
void pop(stack *s) 
{
    if ( !is_empty(s) )
    {
        --s->sz;
    }
}
```

The function `destroy` shall use the original pointer as it was already pointed in my answer to your previous question.

```
void destroy( stack **s ) 
{
    free( ( *s )->v );
    free( *s );

    *s = NULL;
}
```

Also pay attention to that the object of the structure type was also allocated dynamically. So you also need to free it.

The function is called like

```
destroy( &s );
```

The function match should look like

```
int match( char p1, char p2 ) 
{
    if ( p1 == '(' ) return p2 == ')';
    else if ( p1 == '[' ) return p2 == ']';
    else if ( p1 == '{' ) return p2 == '}';
    else return 0;
}
```

The while loop in main will look like

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{')
         push(s, c);
    else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
        int value;

        if ( !top( s, &value ) || !match( value, c ) )
        {
            printf("no\n");
            destroy( &s );
            return 0;
        }

        pop( s );
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented it and it also ran smoothly thank you! I also clarified the concept of the top and pop functions of a stack, two in one, worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: @stfp04 No at all. At least close the previous your question where I showed how the function push should be written.

Comment: How can I close a question? I am really new to this

Comment: @stfp04 In the left side of the answer click an image like v.

Comment: There you go, closed it

Comment: @stfp04 Well done.:)